# Swift - How to get last insert id in Core Data, store it in NSUserDefault and predicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode6

I already create a new entity and save it. Then I want to grab last insert id from first entity then save it into second entity as a reference id.

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)

        let userContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        let userEn = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("UserEntity", inManagedObjectContext: userContext)

        var newUser =  Users(entity: userEn!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: userContext)

        newUser.uname = "Nurdin"

        userContext.save(nil)
```

Then how to save last insert id into NSUserDefault? Because I want to predicate with existing data inside CoreData for matching purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you magically ask core data for the latest id...

but for your example. just add a line after the save to store the ID...

```
    let string = user.objectID.URIRepresentation().absoluteString
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(string, forKey: "userID")
```

... vice-versa ...

```
    let oidString = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userID")
    let url = NSURL(string: oidString)
    let objectID = persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation(url)
```

Comment: then how to retrieve it?

Comment: and vice versa also works.. although note! I wrote the code inline so there might be a typo

Comment: another one thing, is it possible delete object based on object Id?

Comment: yes, fetch the object based on id and then delete it, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050372/core-data-how-can-i-find-and-delete-managed-objects-effectively

Comment: @Daij-Djan : Its not working as we are saving temparory ID and fetching with temparory ID. So object doesn't have permanent ID

Comment: dont get you Im afraid. you cant save & fetch from temporary ID. on saving, the ID is made permanent

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5

There is no such feature in core data to get the last saved Id, but you can achive through NSUserDeafult

here we have created two function for save and retrive the last saved ID.

```
fileprivate func getLastId() -> Int {
    let objUserDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    if let userID =  objUserDefault.value(forKey: "TaskId") as? Int {
        print(userID + 1)
        return userID + 1
    }
    return 1
} 
fileprivate func setTaskId(id: Int) {
    let objUserDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    objUserDefault.setValue(id, forKey: "TaskId")
    objUserDefault.synchronize()
}
```

In getLastId() we are retriving the id and increment by 1 for saving current record. If it saved for first time it will give you 1.

In setTaskId() we are just storing the updated value.