# get last inserted NSManagedObject from CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

This how **NSManagedObject** is created

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:strEntityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjContext];
NSManagedObject * managedObject = (NSManagedObject *)[[NSClassFromString(strEntityName) alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjContext];
//values are mapped into this object
```

Now save **NSManagedObject** to persistent store and fetching currently inserted object like this :

```
NSError *error;
BOOL isDone = [managedObjectContext save:&error];
//BOOL isDone = [managedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tempManagedObject, nil] error:&error];
if (isDone && error == nil){

   //fetch last inserted object here

   //make fetch request
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:strEntityName];
   //make query using fetch request in context      
   NSError *error;
   NSArray *arrFetchRequest = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
   if (arrFetchRequest.count>0){
       //This is last inserted object
       NSManagedObject *managedObject = [arrFetchRequest lastObject];
       return managedObject;
   }
}
```

I have also refered [Swift - How to get last insert id in Core Data, store it in NSUserDefault and predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28363914/1106035). But it will not have permanent object ID in NSManagedObject as we are saving temparory ID and fetching using that and we don't have permanent ID at all.

Canyone share any other options?

Comment: There are lots of better options.  That request will return all objects of that entity type, not just the last inserted.  The simplest is to save the `objectID` and fetch using that.  Make sure to call `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects`.

Comment: @Avi : By using `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects`, it will not get NSManagedObject with permanent ID. Also i will have to use `[NSManagedObjectContext save]` method after it to save records in database.

Comment: Wait.  You think a method called `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` **won't** get permanent `objectID`s?  Explain that, please.

Comment: @Avi : When method called `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` it returns just BOOL value, I will not know what would be permanent ID as CoreData don't provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While inserting NSManagedObject in context, it will have temporaryID (this means it has not been saved to database).

So need to get permanentID  (this means it has been saved to database) for NSManagedObject in context, use `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` and same NSManagedObject will have permanentID

```
if (insertManagedObject)
{
    NSLog(@"Before %@ : %d",insertManagedObject.objectID,insertManagedObject.objectID.isTemporaryID);
    //Obtain permanentID for object
    NSError *error;
    BOOL hasObtainedPermanentID = [managedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:insertManagedObject, nil] error:&error]; //;
    //check if its done
    if (hasObtainedPermanentID && error == nil){

       NSLog(@"After %@ : %d",insertManagedObject.objectID,insertManagedObject.objectID.isTemporaryID);

       //check context has changes and is saved in context
       if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && [managedObjectContext save:&error])
       {
            return insertManagedObject;
       }

    }

}
```